# How to use v-model and props passed to parent from child?

Tags: vue.js

I've been learning vue for a few days now and I'm trying out passing data/props between child and parent. 
Now I have the following child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name1" placeholder="string">
    <input v-model="number1" placeholder="number">
    <p v-text="name1"></p>
    <p v-text="number1"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  props: {
    name1 : String,
    number1 : Number
  }
}
</script>
```

And then parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "@/components/complexComponent4/child.vue"

export default{
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    child
  }
}
</script>
```

Now when I enter some text into the input fields, it displays correctly in the paragraphs, since the props bound to the paragraphs have changed. 
However, I get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name1"

found in

---> <Child>
       <Parent> at src/components/complexComponent4/parent.vue
         <MyComplexView4.vue> at src/views/myComplexView4.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

I read about this error in multiple places on the internet and also in the documentation, and I found that mutating props is deemed an anti-pattern now: 
https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly

Unfortunately I didn't really find anything specific and/or helpful on how to deal with this problem. Especially in context of vue handling primitive data and objects/arrays differently (objects/arrays are passed by reference).

v-model seems to play an important role in leveraging the power of vue, since it enables two-way binds. Therefore I wouldn't want to omit it entirely, unless its use has become so difficult that it doesnt justify the gains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the warning says, you should avoid mutating props *directly* in child component.
So you should emit an event from child to parent to let parent know that prop value had been changed. Parent will change the prop and pass it down to child.

For such purpose there is a syntactic sugar in Vue called [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier.

So your components could be something like this.
Child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input 
      :value="name1" 
      @change="$emit('update:name1', $event.target.value)"
      placeholder="string"
    />
    <input 
      :value="number1" 
      @change="$emit('update:number1', $event.target.value)" 
      placeholder="number"
    />
    <p v-text="name1"></p>
    <p v-text="number1"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  props: {
    name1 : String,
    number1 : Number
  }
}
</script>
```

And parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child :name1.sync="name1" :number1.sync="number1"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from "@/components/complexComponent4/child.vue"

export default{
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    child
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name1: '',
      number1: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or for more complicated cases you can either use v-model and computed properties with setters in child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input 
      v-model="computedName1" 
      placeholder="string"
    />
    <input 
      v-model="computedNumber1" 
      placeholder="number"
    />
    <p v-text="name1"></p>
    <p v-text="number1"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  props: {
    name1 : String,
    number1 : Number
  },
  computed: {
    computedName1: {
      get() { return this.name1 },
      set(value) {
        // some logic
        this.$emit('update:name1', value)
      },
    computedNumber1: {
      get() { return this.number1 },
      set(value) {
        // some logic
        this.$emit('update:number1', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: WoW, thanks, looks great! :D 
Two FollowUps:
1) Since I'm so very new to vue, how can I test if this way, the re-rendering of the parent component doesn't overwrite the data inside the props? I mean, thats the problem with mutating the props directly, so this caveat should be eliminated if I do it like you've shown me right?
 I already reloaded the page after inputting, but when I then checked on the props with the vue debugger the props had changed back to being empty?
2) When I enter numbers into the number field, I get a warning that I entered a string. How to deal with this?

Comment: @baryon123 1) when you are reloading the page – all components would be re-rendered. If you want to store some data permanently... ok, you can store it in localstorage. Look at vue-persistent-state for example. 
2) Updated my answer with computed setters. You can do all your type checks and logic inside them

Comment: this is a fantastic example, particularly when using v-model and getting your data to update via a change stream... either clicking on a link to load the data, or page refresh... well done!

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to change prop passed down to child assign it first to child data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name" placeholder="string">
    <input v-model="number" placeholder="number">
    <p v-text="name"></p>
    <p v-text="number"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  data() {
    return {
      name: null,
      number: null
    }
  },
  props: {
    name1 : String,
    number1 : Number
  },
  mounted() {
    this.name = this.name1;
    this.number = this.number1;
  }
}
</script>
```

When data is changed you can $emit those changes to parent component

1. With **sync**

Parent

```
<child :number1.sync="number1" :name1.sync="name1" />
```

Child

```
watch: {
    name: value => this.$emit('update:name1', value)
    number : value => this.$emit('update:number1', value)
  },
```

2. With **events**

Parent

```
<child :number1="number1" :name1="name1" @changeNumber="value => number1 = value" @changeName="value => name1 = value" />
```

Child

```
watch: {
    name: value => this.$emit('changeName', value)
    number : value => this.$emit('updateNumber', value)
  },
```

Comment: Looks like the perfect answer ! Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A guideline for vue.js is that you can use props to automatically alter data in the child from the parent, but not vice-versa. For altering data of the parent-component, the child-component is supposed to use events. You could consider using two different components for name1 and number1 respectively and bind the values in a two-way-manner by making these components applicable for `v-model`, as it is described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).